# How to open Putty Process without it opens in another window

Tags: c#, process, putty

using this Code

```
    Process process = new Process();
    // p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(p_OutputDataReceived);
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = false;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\putty.exe"; ; // Gets or sets the application or document to start.
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-serial com31 -sercfg 9600,8,n,1,N";//Gets or sets the set of command-line arguments to use when starting the application      
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    process.Start();//Starts (or reuses) the process resource that is specified by the StartInfo property of this Process component and associates it with the component.   
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit(); // wait forever with ping
```

I'm trying to open putty in console application , but any timr I use it it opens in New windows and I cant get to output of the process using `process.OutputDataReceived` event

I'm using code very similar to this to open `Iperf` and it works fine

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Putty` is **not** a `console application` and therefore does not provide output on it's `stdout` and `stderr` streams.

And since it *is* a `windowed application` it does not care whether you start it with the `CreateNoWindow` flag. Try and start `notepad.exe` with that flag, you will see it appearing obviously.

There is however a programm by the creators of `Putty` that provides the functionality you need.

It's called `Plink.exe` and you can download it on their [homepage](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)